# php with html tag redirect syntax

Tags: php, html, redirect

I found this from a website but I just want to make sure if this is correct or there's a better way to do this.

Is this syntax correct?

```
echo “location.href=’http://localhost/register/lemailer.php?nn=$usernick&idz=$userid&ac=$activation_code&ea=$email’;”;
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

header('location.href=lemailer.php?nn='.$usernick.'&idz='.$userid.'&ac='.$activation_code.'&ea='.$email);

This will work for you

Answer (score 2):

I usually use `header()` or (If a header is not an option, which rarely is the case) `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url=<?= $url; ?>">`

The meta refresh does not work for everyone though. So if you want to use that one make sure to have a splash which states that the user will be redirected; if not click `here`

Answer (score 0):

your example uses javascript, i would do it with php:

```
header( 'Location: http://www.yoursite.com/new_page.html' ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

That line of code outputs a javascript location.
It is correct if you want to use it that way.
Otherwise check the php header() function:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Answer (score 0):

you can use this also

```
  echo "<script>window.location.href='http://www.yoursite.com/'</script>";
```